# Strange output with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone explain the reason behind the second output? Also what is the difference between solving using int pointers and char pointers?
The second answer is coming out to be 0.

```
int main()
{
    char arr[] = "geeksforgeeks";
    char *ptr1 = arr;
    char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    printf ("ptr2 - ptr1 = %d\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
    printf ("(int*)ptr2 - (int*) ptr1 = %d",  (int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you typecasting to `int *`  do like this---> `(char*)ptr2 - (char*)ptr1)`

Comment: Actually i want to know the logic behind the answers.

Comment: Serge Ballesta this guy answered your query then

Comment: generic ((data type)ptr2 - (data type)ptr1)/ sizeof(data type)

Comment: Note: `(int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1` is UB.  `"%d"` should be `"%td"`.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers of some type T point to objects of type T.

For example

```
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
int *p = a;
```

If you increase a pointer as for example

```
++p;
```

or

```
p = p + 1;
```

(take into account that these statements are equivalent) it will point to the next object of type T that follows the current object. So the value of the pointer will be increased by `sizeof( T )`  that to provide that the poiner indeed will point to the next element.
In the example above sizeof( int ) is (usually) equal to 4. So the value of the pointer will be increased by 4. 
If you write

```
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
int *p = &a[0];  // the same as int *p = a;
int *q = &a[1];
```

then expression `q - p` will be equal 1 but the difference between the values stored in p and q will ve equal to `sizeof( int )`. p points to the first element of the array and q points to the second element of the array. It is so-called pointer arithmetic.

As for your result with subtracting int pointers then the behaviour is undefined. According to the C++ Standard

> Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one
>   past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined

In your case int pointers do not point to elements of the same array. That they would point to the elements of the same array at least the difference of their values shall be equal to sizeof( int )

Comment: You mean surely not int *q = &[1]; but int *q = &a[1]; :)

Comment: q-p gives zero when I run the above mentioned snippet.

Comment: @user3717384 There was a typo. Try again.

Comment: @Matt McNabb it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because char size is 1-byte, when int is 32Bit (4byte) variable

Answer (score 0):

Edit keep pointer in the original array and ensure correct alignement to avoid undefined behaviour (see comment of Matt McNabb)

Because 3 < sizeof(int).

In pointer arithmetic, `(int *) ptr2 - (int *) ptr1` gives `real_addr_of_ptr2 - real_addr_of_ptr1) / sizeof(int) = 3 / 4`. As it is integer division => 0 - this is **not specified by C++** but is current implementation.

If you use : `char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 8;`, you will get : `(int*)ptr2 - (int*) ptr1 = 2`

As there are more than 8 characters in array, it can work, provided the original array is correctly aligned. To be coherent with the specs, it should have been declared :

```
union {
   char arr[] = "geeksforgeeks";
   int iarr[];
} uarr;
char *ptr1 = uarr.arr;
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour in the case where the difference in bytes is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.  (And also undefined in some cases when it is a multiple).